# PHP/html/mysql Image display

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, src

Hey my php/mysql/html people,

I have this variable that holds a path to an image and then insert it into a db (yes, I am using mysql_real_escape_string) which works perfectly.

```
$file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$path='images\ '. $file_name;
insert into...blah blah blah
```

The path is later pulled from the db and stored in said variable.

```
$path       = $row['file_path'];
```

I am trying to display it with:

```
 // the contents of $path in this case is: images\ cats.jpg
echo "<img src=" . $path . ">";
```

However the image breaks because the only thing that src pics up is: images\
and not the actualname+extension of the image. I know this probably has to do with the slashes, but I am a newbie and could use some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried printing the variable to check if it is showing what you think it is showing? try "echo $path" before you insert into. also try "echo $path" after you retrieve it from the db. does it print what you expect it to?

Comment: just wondering shouldn't the path be images\cats.jpg instead of images\ cats.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your

```
$path='images\ '. $file_name;
```

should be

```
$path='images\'. $file_name;
```

Comment: agreed, however as soon as i delete that space then the rest of my code in the script goes grey. This is due to the fact that the \ will actually escape the '

Comment: so just escape the \ with \\

Comment: that worked! , in terms of getting the full file path. However I am still getting broken pic icon displayed :/

Comment: try echoing $path first and see if the file is actually there

Comment: seems that the path needs to be displayed like: /images/filename.jpg

Comment: so just change the backslash to forward slash and you should be through :)

Answer (score 0):

Print $path variable & see the values.

```
echo $path;exit;
```

You will get value on web browser.

Copy the value displayed on browser & paste it in the URL, if you see the image, your saved path is correct, if not, you have gone wrong in specifying the relative path too the resource.